# I want to use the functions written in the .vimrc file placed on the host side within the Docker

Tags: docker, vim

## what I want to accomplish

- I want to use the functions written in the .vimrc placed on the host side within Docker.

## what I did

- Put the .vimrc file in the /home/akihiro directory on the host side.
- When using the docker run command, mount the /home/akihiro directory on the host side and run the python file in Docker with Vim.

```
akihiro@akihiro-thinkpad-x1-carbon-5th:~$ docker run --rm -it -v /home/akihiro:/home --name test cnn_study:latest
```

- As a result, the settings written in the .vimrc file did not work.
- Next, I started a new container without mounting.
- Created /home/akihiro directory in the container.
- I left the container.
- I copied only the /home/akihiro/.vimrc file on the host side into the container, and re-entered the container.

```
docker cp ./.vimrc 52b28f1ffea8:/home/akihiro
```

- Started up a Python file using Vim.
- As a result, the settings written in the .vimrc file did not work.

Comment: If you use a tool like `vi` to edit files in a container, those changes will be lost as soon as the container exits.  I'd use this path sparingly, probably only to debug why exactly your Dockerfile can't start the service on its own, and would not try to copy in complex user-specific settings.

Comment: If you have access to the `Dockerfile` of that container, then you could simply add something like: `ADD ~/.vimrc .vimrc` (with the appropriate paths). If you don't, then you could write your own `Dockerfile` starting with `FROM cnn_study:latest` and prepare your environment the way you want it. That said, I agree with the other commenter: containers are not workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is mapping the complete /home or /home/akihiro directory on the Container.

You can't do that for 2 reasons:

1. There are more files in that directory. What do you expect happens with them?
   It's not like a OR-function is done on files in both folder.
   Mapping the volume complete replaces the internal folder
2. My gut feeling says that mapping the direcory comes too late in the process.
   The directory is already there in the Container and therefore cannot be overwritten.
   (At least that's how I understand the strange effects I get with mapping sometimes)

What you should do is only map the file:

```sh
$ docker run --rm -it -v /home/akihiro/.vimrc:/home/akihiro/.vimrc --name test cnn_study:latest
```

I do the same with .bashrc (to set the prompt to the name of the Container)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I restarted container using this command: docker run --rm -it -v /home/akihiro/.vimrc:/home/akihiro/.vimrc --name test cnn_study:latest, .vimrc file functions did not work.

Comment: But, using this command: docker run --rm -it -v /home/akihiro/.vimrc:/root/.vimrc --name test cnn_study:latest, .vimrc file functions work!

Comment: Correct, you log in on the Root account, therefore the .vimrc should be in the homedirectory of the root account.